# What does <ice:outputText value="#{exam.testName}"/> mean?

Tags: java, sql, xhtml, ice

I have a xhtml file with `<ice:outputText value="#{exam.testName}"/>`

The part of the webpage associated with that statement just shows the Test Name.
I have the whole java source code and I am trying to find the database query that brings back the test names.  I don't know what exam.testName means and what it refers to in the code for it to get the test name for that page.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is using a **JSF** (Java Server Faces) component; probably from the ICEFaces component library (you should search your xhtml namespaces to be sure, though)

It shows some text obtained from calling `getTestName()` in a bean identified as `exam` (either the bean class is `Exam` or it has a `@Named` annotation specifying such a name for the bean, or it is defined in the `faces-config.xml` file.